# How to add elements to the line item using XPATH

Tags: c#, linq, xpath

How to add sum of all sublineitems bill of rating quantity and ladingquantity to main lineitem?

Main line item is the line item where integer `<LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000010" />` equals integer after the pipe line | of `<PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />`

```html
<Transmission>
  <TransmissionSenderID V="Co" />
  <TransmissionReceiverID V="8004171844" />
  <InterchangeControlNumber V="1" />
  <InterchangeCreationDate V="2019-11-15" />
  <InterchangeCreationTime V="02:00:02" />
  <TotalNumberOfGroupsInTransmission V="00001" />
  <InterchangeUsageIndicator V="T" />
  <Groups>
    <Group>
      <GroupSenderID V="Co" />
      <GroupReceiverID V="8004171844" />
      <GroupCreationDate V="2019-11-15" />
      <GroupCreationTime V="02:00:02" />
      <GroupControlNumber V="1" />
      <TotalNumberOfShipmentsInGroup V="000005" />
      <Documents>
        <Document>
          <DocumentHeader>
            <InvoiceChargeType V="T" />
            <DocumentType V="ORDER" />
            <DocumentProcessingCode C="00" />
            <BOLNumber V="BOL2309460180582136" />
            <BOLIssueDate V="2019-11-14" />
            <InvoiceNumber V="0180582136" />
            <Mode C="S" />
            <FreightTerms V="CC" />
            <INCOTerms V="FOB" />
            <DocumentTotal V="0.0" />
            <CurrencyCode V="USD" />
            <RequestedPickupDate V="2019-12-19" />
            <RequestedDeliveryDate V="2019-12-31" />
            <SpecialInstructions V="SHSV154946" />
            <AlternateQuantities>
              <AlternateQuantity Quantity="12.0" UOM="PK" UOMType="SQ" Characteristic="" />
            </AlternateQuantities>
            <Buyer Name="" Q="ZP" ID="COUSPO001">
              <AlternateIDs />
            </Buyer>
            <Seller Name="" Q="2" ID="CNTR">
              <AlternateIDs />
            </Seller>
            <Parties>
              <Party PartyType="SF">
                <Name V="SHA" />
                <LocationID Q="" ID="" />
                <AlternateLocationIDs>
                  <LocationID Q="" ID="SHA" />
                </AlternateLocationIDs>
                <City V="Shanghai" />
                <Country V="CN" />
                <LocationPurpose V="" />
              </Party>
              <Party PartyType="ST">
                <Name V="LEB" />
                <LocationID Q="" ID="" />
                <AlternateLocationIDs>
                  <LocationID Q="" ID="LEB" />
                </AlternateLocationIDs>
                <City V="Lebanon" />
                <Country V="TN" />
                <LocationPurpose V="" />
              </Party>
              <Party PartyType="VN">
                <Name V="YANGZHOU BAOYI SHOES" />
                <LocationID Q="" ID="4100000423" />
                <AlternateLocationIDs />
                <City V="JIANGSU" />
                <Country V="CN" />
                <LocationPurpose V="" />
              </Party>
            </Parties>
            <DateReferences>
              <DR Type="D" Q="ETA" Date="2019-12-19" />
              <DR Type="D" Q="EST" Date="2019-11-28" />
            </DateReferences>
            <ReservedReferences>
              <RR Type="R" Q="K6" V="86|SEAL230946" />
              <RR Type="R" Q="V3" V="VYG230946|BKG230946" />
            </ReservedReferences>
          </DocumentHeader>
          <Vessel VesselName="VSL230946" VesselNumber="" VesselCountryOfRegistration="" VesselRegistrationNumber="" />
          <Equipments>
            <Equipment Initial="CNTR" Number="230946" Length="0" Type="" TotalContainerVolume="52.06" />
          </Equipments>
          <LineItems>
   <LineItem>
     <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900001" />
     <LineItemType C="LI" />
     <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
     <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
     <PurchaseOrderNumber V="123456789|00020" />
     <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
     <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
    <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
    <BuyerProductID V="" />
     </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
     <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
     <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
     <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
     <UserDefinedReferences>
    <UDR Type="U" Q="CR" V="22859470896|001|0001" Description="" />
    <UDR Type="U" Q="S6" V="|3|20" Description="" />
    <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
     </UserDefinedReferences>
     <LineItemWeight V="2959.54" />
     <LineItemVolume V="104.12" />
   </LineItem>
   <LineItem>
     <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900002" />
     <LineItemType C="LI" />
     <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
     <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
     <PurchaseOrderNumber V="123456789|00020" />
     <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
     <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
    <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
    <BuyerProductID V="" />
     </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
     <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
     <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
     <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
     <UserDefinedReferences>
    <UDR Type="U" Q="CR" V="22859470896|001|0001" Description="" />
    <UDR Type="U" Q="S6" V="|3|20" Description="" />
    <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
     </UserDefinedReferences>
     <LineItemWeight V="2959.54" />
     <LineItemVolume V="104.12" />
   </LineItem>
   <LineItem>
     <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000020" />
     <LineItemType C="LI" />
     <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
     <PurchaseOrderNumber V="123456789|00020" />
     <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
     <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
    <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
    <BuyerProductID V="" />
     </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
     <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="0.0" UOM="PA" />
     <LadingQuantity V="0.0" UOM="PA" />
     <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
     <LineItemWeight V="0.00" />
     <LineItemVolume V="0.00" />
   </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000010" />
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="0.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="0.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
              <LineItemWeight V="0.00" />
              <LineItemVolume V="0.00" />
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900001" />
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
              <UserDefinedReferences>
                <UDR Type="U" Q="CR" V="22859470896|001|0001" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="S6" V="|3|20" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
              </UserDefinedReferences>
              <LineItemWeight V="2959.54" />
              <LineItemVolume V="104.12" />
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900002" />
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
              <UserDefinedReferences>
                <UDR Type="U" Q="CR" V="22859470902|001|0002" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="S6" V="|3.5|20" Description="" />
                <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
              </UserDefinedReferences>
              <LineItemWeight V="2959.54" />
              <LineItemVolume V="104.12" />
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
              <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000900003" />
              <LineItemType C="LI" />
              <LineItemSubType C="SCH" />
              <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
              <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
              <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
              <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
                <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
                <BuyerProductID V="" />
              </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
              <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
              <LadingQuantity V="24.0" UOM="PA" />
           ...
```

After the script  lineitems should look like:

```html
<LineItems>
 <LineItem>
  <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000020" />
  <LineItemType C="LI" />
  <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
  <PurchaseOrderNumber V="123456789|00020" />
  <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
  <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
   <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
   <BuyerProductID V="" />
  </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
  <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="48.0" UOM="PA" />
  <LadingQuantity V="48.0" UOM="PA" />
  <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
  <LineItemWeight V="0.00" />
  <LineItemVolume V="0.00" />
  <UserDefinedReferences>
   <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
  </UserDefinedReferences>
 </LineItem>
 <LineItem>
  <LineItemNumber V="00000000000000000010" />
  <LineItemType C="LI" />
  <TransportationServiceCode Code="" />
  <PurchaseOrderNumber V="0100230946|00010" />
  <AdditionalReferenceNumber V="" />
  <DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
   <CommodityCode Q="" C="M9160" />
   <BuyerProductID V="" />
  </DescriptionMarksAndNumbers>
  <BilledRatedAsQuantity V="144.0" UOM="PA" />
  <LadingQuantity V="144.0" UOM="PA" />
  <LineItemTotalAmount V="0.0" />
  <LineItemWeight V="0.00" />
  <LineItemVolume V="0.00" />
  <UserDefinedReferences>
   <UDR Type="U" Q="19" V="M9160|USDS|0001" Description="" />
  </UserDefinedReferences>
 </LineItem>
</LineItems>
```

I tried to start in LINQ, but need guidance to use XPATH Addafterself

Comment: The question has unnecessary details. First, XPath prior 3.0 do not serialize, but selects or outputs scalar value instead. Because the relation between `LineItemNumber` and `PurchaseOrderNumber`, it looks like you want to group with aggregation. XPath can be used for grouping, but then you would need the host language to iterate over the the grouping keys and after that you would be able to use XPath again for aggregation.

Comment: hi, thanks for the comment:

Comment: do you think which method should i use to aggregate?

Comment: If you are able to use XSLT, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112496/xslt-for-grouping-and-summing-values